# Check for WebForm Errors

Tags: webforms

Some of my website visitors are stating that they are filling out the webform (ver 7.x-4.2) and we are not getting the email. They have not provided any detail (error messages, etc...) and when I login and review the Results tab I do not see their emails. I've tested the webform and I get the emails. My questions are as follows:

1) Is there anyway to look for webform errors in a log file? Where would I look?
2) If a webform is not successfully sent, it won't show in the Results tab correct? When does the submission get recorded?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

The email may not have been sent without any error at the Drupal end. I recently experienced this problem, and found that the mail server was rejecting emails sent "from" someone claiming to be the same host as itself.

In short, Drupal could successfully send the email without knowing that it wasn't received.

We solved the problem by installing the modules "mailsystem" and "mandrilL" and signing up for a free Mandrill account.

Comment: Thanks, but when does the email get posted in the Results tab, once the user hits send and if no errors occur on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the reports that can be found within the admin section of a Drupal site:

- **Status report**, located at */admin/reports/status*.
- **Recent log messages**, located at */admin/reports/dblog*

  (requires core module `dblog` to be enabled).